# Weight exercises while taking a short break

Tags: weights, health-risk, warm-up

I apply the [pomodoro technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomodoro_Technique) while working (computer work/standing desk). That is, one works 25 minutes and takes a 5' break. Rinse, repeat.

Would it be healthy/safe to do exercises with moderate weights, like squats or deadlift during those 5 minutes without any warm up?

The intention is just to pump some blood and introduce some regular physical effort during the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it be healthy/safe to do exercises with moderate weights, like squats or deadlift during those 5 minutes without any warm up?

It's not a good idea to do these exercises without warm up. Especially with whole-body workouts like squats/deadlift. Warm up is crucial for these.

You might be able to do some bodyweight squats/jumping jacks, but I'd avoid weighted squats/deadlift

Comment: Thanks! I'll try with bodyweight exercises (I've plenty of that anyway :-) )